# Reset the amended values in the Else part of an if/else statement by removing the function

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement

Is there an equivalent in JS of the `initial` value in CSS.  When you have a function that you want to behave in a certain way with an if statement but, then in the `else` part you want the values to just be what they they were before the `if` piece of code returned true. I've always re-written the original values as part of the `else`, but this seems to be a galatically inefficient way of doing things, for example:

```
var a = something, b = something_else;

if (a) {
run a function which changes lots of values;
} else {
    re-type the values to what they were before the function ran;
}
```

A more concrete version of what I'm trying to do is below.  I have a forEach method that changes some string values.  If I want to set it so that on the `else` all the code in the initial `if` is ignored I know I can do this by copy and pasting the code under a different function name and setting the second `slice` value to 300, which is the length of the original strings, but this seems a very verbose way of doing things?

There must be a way of setting the `else` code so it removes / kills off the original myresize() function so all the original values hold true?

```
var content = document.querySelectorAll(".generic-content p");

function textSlice() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
        function myresize() {

        content.forEach(function(index) {
            var x2, x3, x4;
            x2 = index.textContent;
            x3 = x2.slice(0, 100) + "[...]";
            index.textContent = x3;

        });
            myresize();
    }


    } else {
        // remove the myresize(); function or somehow kill it
    }
}

addEventListener("resize", textSlice, false);
```

Comment: What is the point? Removing the function doesn't change the values of the variables outside the function had possibly changed. That function will be removed anyway during the garbage collection after the execution of `textSlice` will be finished.

Comment: I need an `else` part of the statement in case the window is re-sized back above 500px after initially being resized below this.  I probably should have given an example with the code in the `if` code block done on its own merits, instead of putting it inside an inner function. Anyway, my point is, is there a method or shorthand way of removing an initial `if` code block inside an `else` code block, instead of manually resetting the values, and i'm guessing that there isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature in JavaScript that restores the initial state of the elements. However, it is relatively easy to build such a feature. Before you start, save the state to a global object, which you can then use to restore the initial state whenever you want.

Try the code below. Note that the first parameter of the `forEach` method is the element itself, not the index. So it isn't right to name it `index`. I've changed it to `item`.

```js
var content = document.querySelectorAll(".generic-content p");
//Save the initial state.
var initial = [];
(function() {
  content.forEach(function(item) {
    initial.push(item.textContent);
  });
})();

function textSlice() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 500) {
    content.forEach(function(item) {
      var x2, x3, x4;
      x2 = item.textContent;
      x3 = x2.slice(0, 100) + "[...]";
      item.textContent = x3;
    });
  } else {
    //Restore the initial state.
    content.forEach(function(item, index) {
      item.textContent = initial[index];
    });
  }
}
addEventListener("resize", textSlice, false);
```

```html
<div class="generic-content">
  <h4>Window Resize Demo</h4>
  <p>first paragraph</p>
  <p>second paragraph</p>
  <p>third paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m afraid it doesn’t.  I want the string length to go back to the original setting if the window width goes back above 500px after being resized. Removing the else statement will prevent this from happening. But my point is, is there anyway of removing the function or code block my using some sort of initial vale method or shorthand and I’m guessing there isn’t.

Comment: A function is a block of code, not a time machine. Removing it won't restore the initial state before it was executed. See my updated answer for a solution.